# Laurent series for $ \log (\frac{z+1}{z-1})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to find the Laurent series for 
$\displaystyle  \log (\frac{z+1}{z-1})$

I used the 
Laurent series of:
$\;\displaystyle \ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} x^n
$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}, |x|<1$

to conclude:
$\;\displaystyle \log (\frac{z+1}{z-1})=\log(1+1/z)-\log(1-1/z)=...=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2}{2k+1}\frac{1}{x^{2k+1}} 
$

I'm wondering: is this allowed to do this in this way?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to develop the Laurent series around $z=0$, however, your function is nice in that area, so there should be no terms with negative exponents. The series you get is valid near $z=\infty$; i.e. for $|z|\gt1$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$ does not blow up near $z=0$, the Laurent series at $z=0$ would be
$$
\pi i+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}
$$
which converges for $|z|\lt1$.